# Error while installing package

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

I am getting error message "start & stop actions r no longer supported. falling back 2 default" when I tried to install a package. How to resolve this?

```
dpkg -i lgtoclnt_19.1.0.2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. It helps if you post the message you get verbatim.

Comment: Error messages are usually given with proper spelling and grammar. Could you please post the exact and full message?